# My instantiated prefab is rotating in scene view but not in game view during play mode. Why?

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality, oculus

I created "rotate.cs" & attached it to a prefab which gets instantiated during play mode. The gameobject which spawns is supposed to rotate constantly. For some reason, it rotates only in scene view & not in game view. Note: I used play mode with oculus quest 2 in VR. I took off the headset to check whether the spawned gameobject's rotation was changing in the inspector or not & it was changing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 250 * Time.deltaTime, 0f, Space.Self);
    }
}
```

Here are the instantiated prefab's components & hierarchy:
[image: inspector window]

Comment: I tested your code and it's working as intended. Can you show how your Prefab's hierarchy appears, and how you assigned the script in the editor?

Comment: @liggiorgio i just added a screenshot of the instantiated prefab's components & hierarchy in the post